# set limit for mandrill webhook

Tags: mandrill

How do I set limit for how many times mandrill webhook can be triggered? I need to trigger click event only once per email. So if someone clicks 100 times, webhook sends POST request only for the first click.

Answer (score 4):

Mandrill will always send on each occasion. It is up to the receiving application to decide what to do with the webhook content.

On a simple level you could record the details of the request in a database using the message ID as a reference, the next time you receive the same information and know it has already been read, you can ignore the duplicate "read" event.

If you are having issues with excessive load due to the quantity of data via webhooks, you can set different URLs per hook type (send, open, click, spam, reject etc).

More information can be found here. http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21738186-Introduction-to-Webhooks